# soapUI - REST API, parameters as variables in request body are empty (*previously posted as guest by accident)

Tags: soapui, rest-api, rest, http

[I am re-posting this; I posted it as "guest" inadvertently.]

soapUI 5.5.0, community edition.

Created REST requests with parameters (style = plain). Wanted to use them in request body as variables, but that did not work. Tried `"${#firstName}"` and `"{firstName}"`

The result was

`"firstName": "",[\n]"`

The call works fine with all values specified.

[image]

Comment: I think you just need to remove the quotes.  But have a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066042/soap-ui-how-to-pass-parameter-from-variable 

If you find it answers your question, please consider adding your own answer to help others in the community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps I followed**

1. Create a new Rest project
2. Add plain parameter to request
3. called it in request body using ${test} (${#test} also works)
4. Right-click the request and click 'Add to Testcase'
5. Now run the request under test suite

[image]

**Note:**

Don't try executing the request in step 3, as a request under project does not have access to method parameters

if you want to use parameter for a request under the project and not test suite, then you have to create a custom property by clicking the project and call it as

**${#Project#[propertyname]}**

[image]

**Note that you have to use #Project and not the project name**

[image]

**Note:**

This has been tested with the below test API,

https://reqres.in/

THe endpoint used for testing is **LOGIN - SUCCESSFUL**

[image]

**References:**

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/SoapUi-getting-request-parameters/m-p/133615/highlight/true#M22780

https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soapui/soapui_properties.htm

Comment: Level can be resource or method both works

Comment: It's interesting that even when I ran the method in the non-REST test suite, it didn't work for me.

The only change I can think of that caused it to work was changing `RESOURCE` to `METHOD`, but it seems unreasonable that that should have been a factor.

Comment: @Guy could you please upvote the answer also by clicking the up arrow

Comment: I did as you requested. It said I don't have enough rep for it to appear publicly.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Guy thank you , welcome to the community